# In code vs in script data generation for integration tests

Tags: c#, tdd, integration-testing, autofixture

This question is very likely to be an opinion based. Yet I'm sure that opinion backed up with solid arguments paves the way to sound decisions.

I do like to generate DB state using Autofixture.

I sincerely hate writing SQL scripts and then coding expectations 'magically' connected with assumptions of that script because I don't like when knowledge/logic spreads across layers/technologies.

I hate how tests fail when some column without default value is added to the table and we must manually edit all failing scripts even for tests that DO not use that column at all.

I like how easily I can derive expectations from DB's state or see how compilation fails when DB schema and hence classes change. And problems occur only with the tests which touch changed column.

My colleagues semi-bought the final argument but continue to insist that ease of debug is more important than brittleness of tests. They argue that randomly generated data is hard to debug and read, they insist that comprehenion of 4 screens of static/stable sql is much more easier than looking at code generating a collection of some objects and then setting 'tested logic affecting' properties values.

Their point is:

> When I explicitly stated that entity A must relate to entity B and
>   later I see that A relates to C I understand what causes the error.
>   But it's hard to interconnect meaningless objects: B and C become
>   indistinguishable by a human being. And to give the identity to the
>   entity we must set other properties which do not affect the logic
>   being tested.

I offered some compromise.
There is usually some kind of 'Name' property which we can manually set an so 'tag' the object.

Their unwillingness to accept the proposal gave me an idea to ask:

> Ok, guys, let's forget about Autofixture with its randomeness for a moment and pretend that
>   we just express DB state as POCO objects and persist them before
>   calling the method under test. We loose the independence of construction logic but we still can explicitly set expectations derived from the state.

Actually I was surprised with the reaction:

> To debug these I need to have Visual Studio opened and execution
>   paused after data is persisted. However, we do not commit transaction
>   - after the test all changes are rolled back. Hence, I need to read uncommited data from within SQL Management Studio. There are so many
>   movements just for debugging a stored procedure. I'd prefer to write
>   sql script rather than POCOS.

So for now it became a discussion about personal preferences and tastes. On the other hand it's very easy to become a biased passionate cherry picker and loose objectivity.

That's why I want to hear some ideas and arguments from the community.

Comment: I found it very hard to understand exactly what you want arguments about. Even so, you're using a Q&A site to start a discussion, this is off-topic. You should call a(nother) meeting with your coworkers.

Comment: I don't expect it to be in a form of discussion. I expect the answer in the form of Script: pros and cons. Pocos: pros and cons. They ought to be for both approaches.

Comment: It is still asking for opinions, and lists of such, both of which are off-topic. This is likely to spark multiple answer where none is right, and none is wrong. Not a good fit for a Q&A site.

Comment: OK, I flagged this question and asked to migrate it to Programmers where such kind of questions accepted more often.

Comment: FWIW, AutoFixture is (mostly) a TDD tool, and was never designed to fill databases with data. Automated tests that involve databases tend to be slow and brittle, and should be avoided if at all possilble. Often, the best option is to replace the data access layer with Test Doubles, but if you *must* involve the database in tests, take heed of the Test Pyramid, and do so only in as few tests as possible.

Comment: If necessary, you can customize AutoFixture to create more 'realistic' values. Here's a proof of concept: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/22/IntegratingAutoFixturewithObjectHydrator

Comment: FIWI, here's the approach I tend to use when I must involve a database in automated testing: http://bit.ly/13m5eeJ

Comment: @MarkSeeman Excuse me, but I do not know what is Test Pyramid. (We run integration tests only at night, they are not a part of a gated checkin)

Comment: @MarkSeemann oh, found it at your link. Will watch the course, thank you.