# Is it possible to insert arbitrary data into table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, integration-testing

`insert into` statement requires providing values for all columns not having defaults.

Is it possible to tell server

> insert whatever value you'd like to, I don't care, the only
>   thing I want is you were satisfied with the data.

In other words I just want to explicitly set the values only for a subset of columns. Is it achievable? (Ok to switch constraints off)

I need this weird functionality for sql scripts that fill DB before integration test. Otherwise, I get a bunch of tests which fail when table schema changes, despite tests do not depend on changed set of columns which are required for `insert into` statements.

Comment: Instead of doing something weird on the database why wouldnt you use a Database mock system? You wont need the database at all.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Is mock system's behavior 100% similar to real SQL Server's behavior? I'd gladly use it but I'm not the only one who make decisions.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: Use mocks in unit tests, not in integration tests. Integration tests are called like this because they integrate the real components.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I understood Jorge's suggestion to use in-memory databases, they probably chave extended API developed exactly for the purpose of testing.

Comment: @voroninp No, it is not 100% you are right about this. But even what you want to do will not behave 100% accurate, I think it will be even worse because you will not have the proper data types and structures to make the proper tests. You can create a copy of your database (with much less data) just to use as a integration tests.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Why not proper data types? It was one of the conditions. I just want to decouple tests from irrelevant structuring of DB (i.e. schema) I have a working [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572272/in-code-vs-in-script-data-generation-for-integration-tests) but it does not use sql scripts and thus not approved by my team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing like this is built-in. Define default constraints or reflect on the table structure using the system catalog views to generate test data at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Random is still a "feature" that you must code in. At work I use [SQL Data Generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/) to generate random data. Yes I can code it using plenty of `NEWID()` and baby name database, but that's not worth my time.

Comment: I don't want that random part to be static because it also has a structure which is irrelevant to the test. Trouble is exactly at this point not at data itself.